# Angular record not binding through directive

Tags: angularjs

I am creating a form which you can add multiple columns which maps to an array.

An example of the record model looks like this

```
record = {'template_name' => 'name', 'detail_section_header' => ['Name', 'Date', 'Assigned To'}
```

Currently, i'm doing it like this

html:

```
<form>
  <div class="x-label">Name</div>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Name" ng-model="record.template_name" autofocus required />
  <table>
    <tr>
      <thead ng-repeat="i in record.detail_section_header track by $index">
        <input type="text" detail-section-header-input index="{{$index}}" />
      </thead>
    </tr>

      ... <buttons to add/remove columns which increments and decrements the size of detail_section_header> ...
  </table>
</form>
```

directive in coffeescript:

```
angular.module('xtiri').directive 'detailSectionHeaderInput', ->
  link: ($scope, el, attrs) ->
  el.on('keyup', ->
    $scope.record.detail_section_header[attrs.index] = el.val()
)
```

What is currently happening is that array (detail_section_header) doesn't populate during the key-up to the bound model (record) until I change another field in the bound model, like the template_name, then it updates. I'm guessing this has something to do with when it digests? Any suggestions on how to make that array populate instantly after typing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular already has [ngModel](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) for binding to input elements, so you don't need a custom directive.

Here's how you should use ngModel to handle two-way binding:

```
  <thead ng-repeat="i in record.detail_section_header track by $index">
    <input type="text" ng-model="record.detail_section_header[$index]" />
  </thead>
```

---

Note: Don't try bind to the `i` variable of the ngRepeat.

For example, this won't do what you expect:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="i" />
```

It would be like doing this:
(code just for demo purposes, Angular internals very different)

```
var detail_section_header = ['Name', 'Date', 'Assigned To'];
var $index = 0;

// This is like using `ng-model="record.detail_section_header[$index]"`
detail_section_header[$index] = 'new value';

// **Correct: **
// We get the expected result,
// `detail_section_header[$index]` has the new value


// This is the equivalent of trying `ng-model="i"`
var i = detail_section_header[$index];
i = newValue;

// **Incorrect:**
// `detail_section_header[$index]` is unchanged
```

Comment: Indeed, that works. I've used ngModel a lot but didn't realize you could tie it to arrays like that. Thanks!